# Someone, have acquired a depth image using the openNI from kinect-v2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, 3d, kinect, point-cloud-library

Someone, have acquired a depth image using the openNI from kinect-v2 ?
My development environment

Windows8.1
Visualstudio2013
Kinect v2

I'm going to try to build the PCL now. However, I'm having problems when not know whether the fetched data kinectv-v2 using openNI.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeSense had shutdown the original OpenNI project when it was acquired by Apple. So OpenNI is no longer fit for kinect v2.

I use Kinect v2, OpenCV, PCL1.7.2 in VS2012 under win8.1.
As the official "Depth Basics" example is not friendly to developer, and I found another [wrapper for kinect v2](https://github.com/UnaNancyOwen/KinectGrabber/tree/Kinect2Grabber). It easy to understand and works good.